# React useEffect to fetch data not finished yet when try to sort data using React Router useSearchParams

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, use-effect

I have a React component that try to load movies first from tmdb API. Then, I create a button to sort the movies using query params. I want to use query params because I want to preserve the URL so that I can share the URL with sort value. (This is for my learning purpose also).

When the page is already rendered and I click the button, it's work fine.

But when I try to reload the page with query params, the query params useEffect is run first before the movies finished loaded.

Here is my code:

```js
import { Box, Button } from '@mui/material';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

import tmdb from '../apis/tmdb';
import MovieCard from '../components/MovieCard';

const MovieList = () => {
    const [queryParams, setQueryParams] = useSearchParams();
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchMovies = async () => {
            try {
                const fetchedMovies = await tmdb.get("trending/movie/week");
                setMovies(fetchedMovies.data.results);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }

        fetchMovies();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const sortMovies = (type) => {
            if (type === 'asc') {
                const sorted = movies.sort((a, b) => a.vote_average - b.vote_average);
                setMovies(sorted);
            }
            if (type === 'desc') {
                const sorted = movies.sort((a, b) => b.vote_average - a.vote_average);
                setMovies(sorted);
            }
        }

        sortMovies(queryParams.get('sort'));
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [queryParams]);

    const setSortParam = (type) => {
        queryParams.set("sort", type);
        setQueryParams(queryParams);
    }

    return (
        <Box sx={{
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            mt: 5,
        }}>
            <Box sx={{
                mt: 5,
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'row',
                justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
                Sort by Rating
                <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    sx={{ ml: 2 }}
                    onClick={() => setSortParam("asc")}
                >
                    Asc
                </Button>
                <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    sx={{ ml: 2, mr: 2 }}
                    onClick={() => setSortParam("desc")}
                >
                    Desc
                </Button>
            </Box>
            <Box sx={{
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'row',
                flexWrap: 'wrap',
                justifyContent: 'space-between',
            }}>
                {
                    movies.map(movie => (
                        <MovieCard key={movie.title} movie={movie}></MovieCard>
                    ))
                }
            </Box>
        </Box>
    );
}

export default MovieList;
```

I try to create new state to track if the movies length > 0, but sometimes it's buggy. I also try to useRef to track if the movies length > 0 but it's not working.

Is there anyway to wait for first useEffect to finish? Or should I use other approach than useEffect to read query params and sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to merge the `movies` state (*i.e. the source of truth*) with the derived state (*i.e. the sorting order of movies*). Derived state generally doesn't belong in state. You can easily derive the sorted `movies` array from the `movies` state and the current `sort` queryString parameter value.

Example:

```
import { Box, Button } from "@mui/material";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

import tmdb from "../apis/tmdb";
import MovieCard from "../components/MovieCard";

// Sort comparators
const sortVoteAverageAsc = (a, b) => a.vote_average - b.vote_average;
const sortVoteAverageDesc = (a, b) => sortVoteAverageAsc(b, a);

// Sorting utility function
const sortVoteAverage = (sort = "asc") =>
  sort === 'asc' ? sortVoteAverageAsc : sortVoteAverageDesc;

const MovieList = () => {
  const [queryParams, setQueryParams] = useSearchParams();
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMovies = async () => {
      try {
        const fetchedMovies = await tmdb.get("trending/movie/week");
        setMovies(fetchedMovies.data.results);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    fetchMovies();
  }, []);

  const setSortParam = (type) => {
    queryParams.set("sort", type);
    setQueryParams(queryParams);
  };

  // create shallow copy of movies state, then sort by sort query parameter
  const sortedMovies = movies
    .slice()
    .sort(sortVoteAverage(queryParams.get("sort")));

  return (
    <Box
      ...
    >
      <Box
        ...
      >
        Sort by Rating
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          sx={{ ml: 2 }}
          onClick={() => setSortParam("asc")}
        >
          Asc
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          sx={{ ml: 2, mr: 2 }}
          onClick={() => setSortParam("desc")}
        >
          Desc
        </Button>
      </Box>
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "row",
          flexWrap: "wrap",
          justifyContent: "space-between"
        }}
      >
        {sortedMovies.map((movie) => (
          <MovieCard key={movie.title} movie={movie} />
        ))}
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

If needed, you can memoize the `sortedMovies` value using the `useMemo` hook with a dependency on the `movies` state and the current `sort` queryString parameter value.

Example:

```
const sort = queryParams.get("sort");

const sortedMovies = useMemo(() => {
  return movies
    .slice()
    .sort(sortVoteAverage(sort))
}, [movies, sort]);
```

Comment: Oh I see, I'm still confused how it's still rerender everytime I click on the button even though there is no state changed, only slice and sort movies via sortedMovies... Because afaik the component will only rerender either there is state change, force update, or new props. Maybe if you can add explanation on that or link to refer, I would be very thankful. But your solution is working fine, thank you!

Comment: @depimomo The route component is rerendered when the URL queryString is updated, which triggers the routed component to rerender. If it's easier, think of the router as providing and updating a React context, subscribers/consumers rerender when the context value updates. `setQueryParams` is like the `navigate` function but for the queryString.

Comment: @depimomo I'm on mobile now, but can try providing a better comment tomorrow if you still need a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a state to track if the movies has been loaded

```
const [moviesHasLoaded, setMoviesHasLoaded] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMovies = async () => {
        try {
            const fetchedMovies = await tmdb.get("trending/movie/week");
            setMovies(fetchedMovies.data.results);
            setMoviesHasLoaded(true);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    fetchMovies();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!moviesHasLoaded) return;
    const sortMovies = (type) => {
        if (type === 'asc') {
            const sorted = movies.sort((a, b) => a.vote_average - b.vote_average);
            setMovies(sorted);
        }
        if (type === 'desc') {
            const sorted = movies.sort((a, b) => b.vote_average - a.vote_average);
            setMovies(sorted);
        }
    }

    sortMovies(queryParams.get('sort'));
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [queryParams, moviesHasLoaded]);
```

Comment: I already try this kind of solution but sometimes it's not loading the sorted movies, there was kinda "glitch" happen when the first useEffect called twice and replace the sorted movies :") . I think it's because I have my React Strict Mode on. Should I just turn it off?